# Can I Create my own Emoji?

Tags: emoji-keyboard

I have been searching for a while and couldn't find what I want!
I would like to create my own Emoji, but all the apps or sites I have tried are creating "Stickers"! I want to create this Mini Emoji that I can send for Example through Whatsapp messages.
Is this possible by any chance?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

You can create one & assign it a Unicode value by finding an empty slot no-one has yet used… but no-one else would know what it was & would never be able to see it.

At best, all they would see would be the 'can't find the glyph' box ⌷